# Download and store images for offline use React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm in the process of building an iOS application that will, when prompted by the user, fetch a large JSON file containing image URLs.

How can I download these images so that they will be available for use by my application even when it has no access to wifi/data?

Answer (score 6):

React Native has poor support to binary data, you are not be able to get the binary data directly via `fetch`. However you can use XMLHttpRequest in 0.30 branch or `CameraRoll`, refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30737226/react-native-upload-image-to-amazons-s3).

If you want to persist those image data, consider use [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html).

There're also several open source modules help you deal with file access if you want to store the images in file system.

[react-native-fs](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs)

[react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob)

NOTE: react-native-fetch-blob has been discontinued. [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob) is a fork of it that is still maintained. When using npm, don't include react-native-fetch-blob but rn-fetch-blob instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response! How can you use AsyncStorage for images? From what I've read it seems like AsyncStorage can only be used with String data.

Comment: new XMLHttpRequest will return a BASE64 encoded string, that can be stored in AsyncStorage, if you're using CameraRoll you can store URI of the image.

Comment: You might want to consider `react-native-fetch-blob` https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/228