# What is best approach for upload IMAGE And PDF from app with Good Performance?

Tags: react-native, upload, blob

We want the user to upload their image to the backend and the backend will do some OCR and AI Learning behind the backend.
So the image cannot be too low resolution.
May i know what is the best approach for uploading HD Images from Frontend to the back end?
Should I zip it before sending it to the backend Blob?
Does GZIP helpful for this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the below approach:

1. You can get images from the user device using an [image picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-picker) and for pdf you can use [document picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-document-picker)
2. After that upload it using Axios with base64 or URI using backed multipart image upload API [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57967536/7846071) either you can upload using fetch call [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42273224/7846071)