# React-Native image upload

Tags: reactjs, react-native, file-upload

Is it possible to upload file (images) to server with react-native using FormData? Tried to use it like this:

```
var data = new FormData();
  data.append('file', file);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  var id = 5;
  fetch('http://192.168.1.104:3000/app/complaint/uploadFile?id='+id,{
    method:'POST',
    body: data,
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;',
    },
  });
```

For `React`, `FormData` works as expected but for `React-Native` not working.

I have also tried (used in react - working)

```
const data = fetch('http://192.168.1.104:3000/app/complaint/uploadFile?id='+id, {
        credentials: "same-origin",
        method:'POST',
        body: dataval,
        timeout: 1000000000,
      });
```

But nothing works,

In the `back-end server`, I am upload using

```
var d = require('domain').create()    
d.run(function safelyUpload () {
        var file=req.file('file').upload({dirname: path.resolve(sails.config.appPath, folder),
        }, function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {
          if (err) return res.serverError(err);
          else{
            sails.log.debug('Complaint File data : ' +util.inspect(uploadedFiles, {showHidden: true,depth: null}));
          }
        });
});
```

Is there any other ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example to upload image using [Fetch API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#using-fetch)

```
const photo = {
  uri: user.profilePicture,
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  name: 'photo.jpg',
};

const form = new FormData();
form.append("ProfilePicture", photo);

fetch(
  URL,
  {
    body: form,
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.token
    }
  }
).then((response) => response.json())
.catch((error) => {
  alert("ERROR " + error)
})
.then((responseData) => {
  alert("Succes "+ responseData)
}).done();
```

Credits https://stackoverflow.com/a/36649457/5315786

Comment: thanks @Pir Shukarullah Shah                                                                              It just worked by replace    data.append('file',file);  ===>    data.append('file', {
        uri: file.uri,
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        name: 'testPhotoName'
      });                                                                                                               It worked , I don't know how, the file object also contains uri, type.     However the problem is solved